# How do I perform an upper-case conversion on strings as pointers

Tags: c++

I'm modifying some existing code written in C++ that uses string pointers, but struggling to understand why I'm having so much difficulty using the toupper() function, or reducing the ASCII value by 32 to perform a case conversion.  I have successfully achieved what I want, with minimal C++ knowledge, but I'd like to improve on the present code which — in order to simply prove a technical point — contains an if condition for every letter of the alphabet.

Other than my difficulties getting to grips with C++ syntax and rules, my attempt is working fine as I want.

The existing code defines 'buf' as follows:

```
static void c_write(Ldisc ldisc, const char *buf, int len)
{
from_backend(ldisc->frontend, 0, buf, len);
}
```

I then added the following, for each of 26 letters of the alphabet, in order to prove my point.

```
if (buf[0] == 97)  buf="A";
if (buf[0] == 98)  buf="B";
if (buf[0] == 99)  buf="C";
if (buf[0] == 100) buf="D";
```

...and so on etc.

If I replace my 26 conditions with the following, then compilation fails.

```
if (buf[0]>=97 && buf[0]<=122)
{
buf[0]=buf[0]-32;
}
```

The message was "(376) : error C2166: l-value specifies const object"

I also tried using the toupper() function, but obtained unsatisfactory results there, either crashing the routine or returning a spurious value.

To the extent that it might help to understand the context in which buf[] is being used, the existing code contains the following working section.

```
switch (buf[0]) {
case CTRL('M'):
if (ldisc->protocol == PROT_TELNET && ldisc->telnet_newline)
ldisc->back->special(ldisc->backhandle, TS_EOL);
else
ldisc->back->send(ldisc->backhandle, "\r", 1);
break;
case CTRL('?'):
case CTRL('H'):
if (ldisc->telnet_keyboard) {
ldisc->back->special(ldisc->backhandle, TS_EC);
break;
}
case CTRL('C'):
if (ldisc->telnet_keyboard) {
ldisc->back->special(ldisc->backhandle, TS_IP);
break;
}
case CTRL('Z'):
if (ldisc->telnet_keyboard) {
ldisc->back->special(ldisc->backhandle, TS_SUSP);
break;
}
default:
ldisc->back->send(ldisc->backhandle, buf, len);
break;
```

Comment: You can compare characters, such as `buf[0] == 'a'` or `buf[0] >= 'a' && buf[0] <= 'z'`. No need to memorize the ASCII table in order to write unreadable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is very simple, in this

```
static void c_write(Ldisc ldisc, const char *buf, int len)
```

`const` is a promise not to modify the string pointed at by `buf`. So obviously trying to convert it to upper case is not allowed. That's what your error *"(376) : error C2166: l-value specifies const object"* is trying to tell you.

It seems reasonable that a function whose (apparent) purpose is to write a string would not modify that string. So if you need to convert to upper case I would say that the correct place to do that is before you call `c_write`, not as part of `c_write`.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean.  I'm curious why I'm not getting any problems when I use if (buf[0] == 97)  buf="A"; however.  In fact the approach not only compiles, but works perfectly and converts all it sees.  Okay, just saw the additional comments, thanks I understand.  Should I be able to create a new string by using toupper()?

Comment: The code `buf = "A"` does not modify the string being pointed at by `buf`. It makes `buf` point at completely new string. That's perfectly OK.

Comment: @OsoB Pointers - you must always have clear in your head the difference between the pointer and what it's pointing at. In `const char* buf` what is const is what's being pointed at, the pointer itself is not const (that would be `char* const buf`).

Comment: @OsoB `toupper` operates on **characters** not strings. I guess that's why it didn't work for you before. If you want to create a new string then you are going to have to allocate some memory for it, and then use toupper on each character.

Comment: At this moment, <buf> only contains a single keypress character, but I can see it's going to be necessary to convert the string prior to the c_write routine, as you say. Thanks.